# How to find Magento Cloud DB credentials?

Tags: magento2, database, magento-cloud

I've one integration environment it was working well but one of my developers deleted the `env.php`, now I can't make it work again.

How could I find my database credentials to my integration env in my Magento Cloud panel or configurations?

Comment: only env.php store database details in file. in your case please check your old backup of app folder (if its you have). that can only helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your terminal, you might see the data to do the connection between the services with this Magento Cloud CLI command below.

```
magento-cloud relationships -e environment
```

> environment = integration|staging|production

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if it works for you;

1. Access your magento cloud via ssh and then run that comment:

`$ echo $MAGENTO_CLOUD_RELATIONSHIPS`

2. decode the result of that is over base64 encoding:

`$ php -r "echo json_encode(base64_decode('BASE_64_RESULT'));"`

It must show the value you want.

Good Luck.